# Shine PDF - Fatal Error after EE version update

Tags: ee2-upgrades, shine-pdf

After updating EE to v2.11.3 a previously working setup of Shine PDF has started to error out with the following:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Channel::Channel() in /SERVER_PATH/expressionengine/third_party/shine_pdf/mod.shine_pdf.php on line 17

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Asked the question on Slack and got the following reply from Stephen Sweetland:

"You need to update your plugin, if that’s not an option, look for parent::Channel() in your plugin scripts, replacing it with parent::__construct();"

Updating wasn't an option as there hasn't been an update from the developer for a while.

After replacing the above code the add-on was again working as expected aside from some PHP warning messages. That will have to do for now.

Hopefully this might help someone else and thanks to Stephen for the fix.